# SVG getTotalLength() won't return the right size for non-scaling-stroke - get SVG scale

Tags: javascript, css, svg, responsive

I'm using javascript to get a path length and apply half of it to the `stroke-DashArray`. My problem is that I use `vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"` so that no mather the scale, it allways keeps a `stroke-width:2px;` The non-scaling seems to affect every part of the stroke properties including the DashArray so I need to get the scale of the svg to then scale `path.getTotalLength();`.

Is there a way to get the SVG computed scale using javascript to use as multiplier of the path lenght?

I made a [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/scharpentier0/pen/jwPPGa?editors=1111) to demonstrate the issue. Just resize the view port to see the stroke change.

Comment: I think you are right, the specs sais that non-scaling-stroke should only affect the stroke width. But I will still need a way to know the scale of the svg for now since it will have this behavior for most people

Comment: `path.getBoundingClientRect().width/path.getBBox().width` will return a scale number that's about right. Case closed i guess.

Comment: Specifying a pathLength yourself might help https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/pathLength

Comment: Well if I do that it still does the same thing: [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/scharpentier0/pen/VWvwKa)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would just like to draw more attention to Sam's comment/answer above, which worked for me!

`path.getBoundingClientRect().width/path.getBBox().width` will return a scale number.

You can then multiply the scale by the length of the path with `path.getTotalLength() * scale;`

Answer (score 1):

For anyone struggling with this now, the scaling solution suggested above wasn't working for me, which I think is because I'm not sizing my svg proportionally (it is set to fill the browser window). I discovered a straightforward solution for my use case with boundingClientRect and the pythagorean theorem though:

```
let boundingClient=el.getBoundingClientRect();
let pathLength=Math.sqrt(boundingClient.width**2 + boundingClient.height**2);
```

This gets it pretty spot-on for me, and it just needs to be recalculated whenever the window resizes.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you must divide the viewbox size / SVG width

```html
  <!doctype html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
  </head> 
  <body>
    <button onclick="dashAni(myPath, 50, 3500)">start</button>
    <svg id="mySVG"  width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 500 500">
        <path 
        vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"
        id="myPath" d="M 50,250 c 0 -100   150 -100   200 0 
                                      c 50 100   200 100   200 0
                                      c -0 -100   -150 -100   -200 0
                                      c -50 100   -200 100   -200 0
                                      z" 
        stroke="#eee"
        stroke-width="5" fill="none" />
    </svg>
    <script>
      var dashAni = function(path, length, duration){
        var dashPath = path.cloneNode(true);
        mySVG.appendChild(dashPath);
        var pathLen=path.getTotalLength()/2.5;  
        var aktPos=0
        var sumSteps = duration / (1000/60) // 60 pics per second
        var step=0;
        var pathAnim;
        dashPath.setAttribute('stroke-dasharray', length + ' ' + (pathLen - length));
        dashPath.setAttribute('stroke', "red");
        dashPath.setAttribute('stroke-dashoffset', aktPos);

        var anim=function(){
           aktPos = pathLen/sumSteps*step*-1;
            //aktLen = easeInOutQuad(step/sumSteps)*len;
           dashPath.setAttribute('stroke-dasharray', length + ' ' + pathLen);
           dashPath.setAttribute('stroke-dashoffset', aktPos);

           if (step <= (sumSteps)){
            step++;
            pathAnim = setTimeout(anim, 1000/60) //1000/60 pics/second
            } else {
              mySVG.removeChild(dashPath);
              clearTimeout(pathAnim);
            }
        }
       anim();
      }
    </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```